# On the Subtleties of Sparseness in Chapel

Tags: multidimensional-array, slice, sparse-matrix, hpc, chapel

Given a *dense* domain `dom: domain(n);` where n < 3, the declaration `sps1: sparse subdomain(dom);` yields a sparse subdomain `sps1` of `dom`. With `sps1` the usual array/matrix slicing is possible. That is, given a matrix `A: [sps1]` one can take n - 1 dimensional slices of `A`. However, the usual matrix operation `transpose()` is not applicable.

Defining a second matrix `B:[sps2]` over another sparse subdomain `sps2 = CSRDomain(dom)` enables one to take `transpose()`s of `B`, but the ability to slice into `B` is forfeit.

Both of these abilities would seem to be that which one should always have access to. Is there a better way to declare sparse subdomains that preserves the two?

Comment: Would you mind to formulate the MCVE-code in >>> https://tio.run/##pc9NC4JAEAbg@/6KwZNCKNHNpUNogVB68BJUh023EnRd9qOI6LdvlmLUrXwvM@/lYSY7EU5LY6CLlhSW5FprFaQYZTU7FEdohlTwTxhMYYL76nmo234gSZisZlHcSDcYuy4bIRiUpzGQuOM3cCaiPTPlREjaHuuDfDWQep/XFSmY3f/hQF4RzmkOQWo7X9@sfdh8SDsQlJQYoYsoFC0bx4riReNTpTmESTzfMgscbMwD

Comment: sorry, I don't understand your question @user3666197

Comment: No problem, Sir. Just have proposed to use an online Chapel terminal, ( with built in persistence ) for sketching a code that will run and that can demonstrate here the concept of testing approaches ( as simply as just a Ctrl+C / Ctrl+V a persistent ( actually self-contained state ) hyperlink-URL, as was posted above, to "jump"-into a ready-to-run MVCE-code ( the standard StackOverflow culture of problem formulation ). **Anyway, enjoy the great [tag:chapel] language, Sir.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a better way to declare sparse subdomains that preserves the two?

I think you are just hitting a shortcoming of the current implementation as of Chapel 1.16.0.

`COO` sparse arrays & domains, the language's default sparse distribution, created with `sps1: sparse subdomain(dom)`, are not yet supported in the `LinearAlgebra.Sparse` module, so there is no library-supported transpose.

`CSR` sparse arrays & domains, `LinearAlgebra`'s default (and only supported) sparse distribution, created with `sps2 = CSRDomain(dom)`, do not yet support slicing.

Both of these should be possible some day as sparse arrays and Linear Algebra features are further developed.

Comment: FWIW, working around these should be possible today. Implementing a `COO` transpose wouldn't be too hard. Working around `CSR` slicing is a little harder, but still possible if you're willing to dive into the array internals.